# Install sudo when having sudo permissions, but no root access?

Tags: linux, sudo, raspberry-pi

I'm messing with a Raspbery Pi logged into the pi user, and here's what's happening:
When I run something with `sudo`, I see `-bash: sudo: command not found`. When I run `apt-get install sudo`, I see

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

This would make me think that the `pi` user simply doesn't have enough permission to use `sudo` or install it. But, when I run `groups pi`, I see

```
pi : pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev spi i2c gpio
```

Note the `sudo` in that list. That means that `pi` should have permissions to use sudo. So what's the deal? In other words, is the permission to use `sudo` enough permission to install sudo and then use it?

Comment: `sudo`, if installed, will permit user pi to `sudo su -` and such.  If `sudo` package is not installed, the membership of group `sudo` is somewhat pointless at that stage.

Comment: Which pi distro are you using? What additional config have you done?

Comment: @steve why do you ever need to use `sudo` and `su` together. They are alternate solutions to the same problem (`sudo` is newer, more powerful, more adaptable). Just use `-s` option. But don't. Don't use a `root` shell (except in a docker container, as they reset when shutdown).

Comment: @steve you don't need to `sudo su`. That's saying "_Hello sudo, please can I have root... thankyou. Now hello su, although I'm already root please can I have root... Ok thankyou_". There's very little point in it, and you can use `sudo -s` (and in some cases even just `sudo`)

Comment: Theo, "_Note the `sudo` in that list. That means that pi should have permissions to use sudo._". Not really, no. That is just a list of groups for your user account. When you have the `sudo` command installed, its default settings allow members of the `sudo` group certain access that wouldn't otherwise be permitted. But membership of the `sudo` group is nothing special in itself.

Comment: If you're the only admin user on the system, just su to root and forget about sudo altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The message `-bash: sudo: command not found` is bash telling you that the command `sudo` is not found. As you correctly identified, and tried to install it. But you can't install it because you don't have permission, because you can't use `sudo`.

So where is `sudo`. I think it is installed by default, but may depend on the OS that you are running (you did not say), and other things (did you remove it, did you do some custom install). It could also be that `sudo` is installed but not in your PATH. Try `/usr/bin/sudo` (if that works then your PATH variable is broken).

Comment: in case sudo is not installed, how to install (su)

Comment: If you know the root password then you can use `su`, else you can remove the SD card fix the problem on another machine: The easiest fix that I can think of is to add a root password.